# Display a timer in a custom UIcollectionview cell's label

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have created a custom collection view cell class with its own xib file. I wish to display a countdown running timer.

I have a working function that can display a timer :

```
class Mainview: UIviewcontroller{
     // get the timer value that I want to countdown, e.g 15 mins
     // then I will pass the the value to the cell class
}


class TimerCell : UIcollectionviewcell{

  func timerRunning() {

            timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1

            if (timeRemaining > 0)
            {
                let minutesLeft = Int(self.timeRemaining) / 60 % 60
                let secondsLeft = Int(self.timeRemaining) % 60
                self.timerLabel.text = "Refreshes in \(minutesLeft):\(secondsLeft)"
             }

 func runtime(){
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerRunning), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
            }
}
```

But because now i implement this function in the cell class, the timer wont run. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks guys.

Comment: where you call it , it's better to post full code

Comment: @Sh_Khan I edited the question

Comment: Note `scheduledTimer` already adds it to the current run loop, so manually adding it to the run loop is unnecessary. And assuming `timer` is both weak and optional, I'd suggest `timer?.invalidate()` before creating and scheduling the timer with `scheduledTimer`. But this is all unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Where do you actually start the timer? I.e. where do you call `runtime`? And did you really mean to define `runtime` _inside_ `timerRunning`? It looks like a brace is missing there.

Comment: @Rob I start the timer when the main view is appear. You can ignore all my code actually, I mainly want to know to to display a running countdown timer in a UIcollectionview cell class?

Comment: @Rob I just need one cell for the timer, any guidance on how to do that? I implemented the code inside the cell class, the timer wont run itself automatically, the timer just stay static.

Comment: @Rob, sorry for my mistake. I call the runtime in my the cell class viewdidload, and the timer run 1 second everytime when the cell being reuse.

Comment: @Rob I manage to call the runtime() correctly, but everytime i scroll up the cell it reset the cell again, how can I stop it being reuse and let the timer to continue running no matter where I scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. I would not suggest using the calls to your timer handler to

   ```
   timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1
   ```

   I would instead save the `nextRefreshTime` and calculate the time elapsed between the current time and `nextRefreshTime` to display the time remaining.
2. Note, when you call `scheduledTimer`, that adds it to the run loop for you, so you don't have to also add it to the run loop yourself.

   Or, if you want to use `.commonModes` on your runloop to allow the label timer to continue during scrolling, just create the `Timer` with `init`, and then add it to your runloop.

   But it doesn't make sense to use `scheduleTimer` and `add` it to your run loop again.
3. I would get out of the business of calculating minutes and seconds yourself. You can use `DateComponentsFormatter` to nicely display the amount of time remaining.
4. You talked about starting your timer in `viewDidLoad`. But `UICollectionViewCell` has no such method (and if you create one of that name, it won't use it). Instead, call some method to configure the cell in `cellForItemAt`.
5. Model objects, like when the next data refresh is going to take place, don't belong in the cell. Cells are transitory UIKit objects that will go in and out of memory as you scroll, so it shouldn't be keeping track of this. You should have your own model for that, and the view controller is responsible for facilitating the communication of this information to the cell as the cell is presented:

   - configuring the cell initially with the `nextRefreshTime`; and
   - posting some notification whenever the `nextRefreshTime` changes.

   The cell will then:

   - add itself as an observer to that notification, updating its `nextRefreshTime`;
   - whenever that notification, cancel any prior "label update" timer, if any, and start a new one if necessary;
   - That label update handler should update the label

Thus:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    static let resetTimerNotification = Notification.Name("someuniqueidentifier")

    // this handles the data refreshes (or whatever), say every two minutes, or whatever

    private var nextRefreshTime: Date? {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: ViewController.resetTimerNotification, object: nextRefreshTime)
            refreshDataTimer?.invalidate()
            if let when = nextRefreshTime {
                refreshDataTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: when.timeIntervalSince(Date()), repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
                    print("timer fired")
                    self?.resetTimer() // presumably, defer this until after the data refresh is done
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private weak var refreshDataTimer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "TimeRemainingCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TimeRemaining")

        resetTimer()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapResetButton(_ sender: Any) {
        resetTimer()
    }

    private func resetTimer() {
        nextRefreshTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(120) // or however you want to do this
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // lets imagine that cell 0 is the TimeRemainingCell

        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TimeRemaining", for: indexPath) as! TimeRemainingCell

            cell.configure(for: nextRefreshTime)

            return cell
        }

        ... configure other types of cells
    }
}
```

and

```
class TimeRemainingCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    // MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var timeRemainingLabel: UILabel!

    private var nextRefreshTime: Date? {
        didSet {
            labelUpdateTimer?.invalidate()

            if nextRefreshTime != nil {
                let timer = Timer(fire: nextRefreshTime!, interval: 0, repeats: false) { [weak self] timer in
                    // note, if cell is deallocated for any reason, let's stop the timer

                    guard let strongSelf = self else {
                        timer.invalidate()
                        return
                    }

                    strongSelf.updateLabel()
                }
                RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
                labelUpdateTimer = timer
            }
        }
    }

    private weak var labelUpdateTimer: Timer?

    /// Formatter for time remaining
    ///
    /// Note, this gets us out of manually calculating minutes and seconds remaining

    private static let formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let _formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        _formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
        _formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
        _formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
        return _formatter
    }()


    // MARK: - init/deinit methods

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addNotificationObserver()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        addNotificationObserver()
    }

    deinit {
        labelUpdateTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    // MARK: - Configuration methods

    /// Add notification observer

    private func addNotificationObserver() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: ViewController.resetTimerNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] notification in
            self?.nextRefreshTime = notification.object as? Date
            self?.updateLabel()
        }
    }

    /// Configure the cell for your model object.
    ///
    /// Called by collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:).
    ///
    /// Also starts the refresh timer.
    ///
    /// - Parameter object: Your model object

    func configure(for nextRefreshTime: Date?) {
        self.nextRefreshTime = nextRefreshTime
    }

    // MARK: - Label updating

    private func updateLabel() {
        let now = Date()

        if let when = nextRefreshTime {
            timeRemainingLabel.text = TimeRemainingCell.formatter.string(from: now, to: when)
        } else {
            timeRemainingLabel.text = "No time remaining"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bro, I got the duration from API, lets say 15 minutes. How do I apply that into your solutions?

Comment: In `resetTimer`, add 15 * 60 rather than 2 * 60 in my example.

Comment: bro what if I wanna call API and reload my collectionview after the timer ends, where can I call it?

Comment: Where I put the timer handler for `refreshDataTimer`, in addition to resetting the timer you’d presumably `reloadData` for the collection view, or what have you.

Comment: bro, I failed to put in the value into function resettimer(), because the value comes back from API after it create the timer. How to make sure it the value from API then only create the timer?

Comment: bro, i found out when I scrolling the timer will stop, is there any way to prevent the timer being stop when i scroll?

Comment: @karenr - "How to make sure it the value from API then only create the timer?" Remove `resetTimer` from the timer handler and put it inside the completion handler of your network request.

Comment: bro ya...i found out the way to solve the timer value...but now got the scrolling issue

Comment: @karenr - "when I scrolling the timer will stop" ... create a local var for the timer (not with `scheduledTimer`), add it to your runloop with `.commonModes`. See revised example

Comment: It's a silly thing, but I'd appreciate it if you'd refrain from calling me "bro".

Comment: sorry for calling you that...i got crash on RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)

Comment: and where to define nextFireDate??

Comment: Use nextRefreshTime

Comment: Yes if I use nextrefrshtime the runloop will crashed

Comment: any update on the solution? I tried with different approach also failed